# EF Core Self Referencing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want a user to have many followers and many people they are following.

Right now im getting this error.

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Following' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.

```
// ApplicationUser File.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // OTHER PROPERTIES ABOVE
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser > Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser > Followers { get; set; }
}

// Context File
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an extra class to accomplish that. Something like this should work:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    // OTHER PROPERTIES ABOVE
    public virtual ICollection<UserToUser> Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserToUser> Followers { get; set; }
}

public class UserToUser 
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set;}
    public string UserId { get; set;}
    public ApplicationUser Follower { get; set;}
    public string FollowerId {get; set;}
}

// Context File
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserToUser>()
        .HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.FollowerId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserToUser>()
        .HasOne(l => l.User)
        .WithMany(a => a.Followers)
        .HasForeignKey(l => l.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserToUser>()
        .HasOne(l => l.Follower)
        .WithMany(a => a.Following)
        .HasForeignKey(l => l.FollowerId);
}
```